# Pass an object from one fragment to another WHEN orientation changes

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

It seems like a duplicate question but actually the answers in similar question don't address my problem: I'm making a game (slide puzzle) where the state (array of numbers) of the board is important. So, when orientation changes I want to save this array from fragment 1 (which will be on screen only in portrait mode) and pass it to fragment 2 (which will be on screen only in landscape mode). So far I managed to get this (in onCreate of the activity that holds the fragments):

```
GameFragment gameFragment = new GameFragment();
gameFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());

GameFragment9 gameFragment9 = new GameFragment9();
gameFragment9.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());

if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.container, gameFragment, "fragmentGame")
                            .commit();
}
else if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.container, gameFragment9, "fragmentGame9")
                            .commit();
}
```

Also I learnt how to save the state of one fragment but this is not exactly what I want because I don't want the last fragment to be rebuild, just put a new fragment with information from the first fragment. I was thinking about using onConfigChange to detect when the screen changed and there do something, but don't know how to do that something.

Answer (score 0):

ViewModel can be answer for your question. Create list of numbers and wrap it with LiveData (optional). Get numbers via ViewModel and save them via ViewModel. Inside `onViewCreated` set text from ViewModel. Like

```
textView.text = viewModel.numbers
```

> Only important thing is exactly same ViewModel should be used inside
>   activity and its child fragments

you can achieve this by providing same owner to ViewModel during initialization time of ViewModel